# Always use tabular figures with MinionPro

Tags: minionpro

When using the pacakge `MinionPro` (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro) with `pdftex`, it uses proportional figures by default. With the package `tabfigures`, it is possible to use tabular figures in certain places (with, e.g., options `toc`or `bib`). However, I couldn't find a way to *always* use tabular figures. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please provide more information about the `MinionPro` package. It doesn't appear to be part of the TeXLive distribution. Is it a commercial package?

Comment: The package itself is not commercial (the fonts are), see link in my edit.

Comment: MinionPro has a `\figureversion` command which works well with standard classes. Which document class do you use?

Comment: I'm using `article`. I'm aware of the `\figureversion`command, but how I understand I would have to patch page numbers, `theorem` environments etc. manually which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\renewcommand{\familydefault}{MinionPro-TLF}` works for my purposes. (Put `MinionPro-TOsF` if you want old style figures.)